# Xamarin, Android: Customize the standard notification

Tags: android, xamarin

We are using our server to send push notifications to each individual phone. But I'd like to customize the layout of the notification a little but I couldnt find out how. The notification looks like this:[image]

So there is somewhat a custom layout already there, with this little bell. The title and the text come from the server and the "BOOK OF LIFE"  from the app. So there must be a way to override this, right? I was able to get to the notification's text like this:

```
    protected override Android.App.Notification BuildNotification(Context context, PushMessage pushMessage)
    {
        // TODO customize the notification
        pushMessage.Text = "xy";
        return base.BuildNotification(context, pushMessage);
    }
```

But I just cannot find a way to change the layout. How would I override the bell and the general layout?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Easier than hoped - this regards all GCM notifications.

```
protected override void OnPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage pushMessage)
    {
        base.OnPushReceived(context, pushMessage);
        SendNotification(pushMessage.Message, pushMessage.Title, context);
    }

    void SendNotification(string message, string title, Context ctx)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(ctx, typeof(ReadAsset));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)ctx.GetSystemService
            (Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
```